# How to increment all rows in a column in Excel?

Tags: excel, csv, increment

How do I increment all rows in column A by 4?
For example, I want to increment the current values in A5 to A250 by 5.

Thanks.

Comment: Excel has wonderful help buddy - do not neglect it!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Add `4` into any blank cell
2. Copy this cell
3. Select the range you want to increment
4. *Paste Special*->*Add*->Ok

Done!

Answer (score 1):

In B1 column enter this formula :

```
= A1 + 5;
```

then press enter, then go to B1 cell, ctrl + c, block B2 until B250 cell, paste.